# How do I make horizontal scrollbar handler appear on the rightmost side, using only css?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have a wide div

```
.wide-div{
    width: 3800px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-right: 160px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Its working BUT upon first display the scrollbar scroll location is at leftmost side.

How do I make it appear on the rightmost side, so that I can scroll to the left, using css only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add direction: rtl to a parent div or body

```
body {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqxbjy89/1/)